# How to Save a Boolean Value in C#

Tags: c#, save, boolean

I am making a game similar to "Make it Rain" or "Cookie Clicker." I have settings where you can purchase items to make each click of the cookie produce more cookies. I have been trying to make the game save the variable. For example, each click produces a cookie. If you have 100 cookies, you can buy a cookie cutter, so each click produces 5 cookies, and so on. I have booleans called cookiecutters, which are false. If the user buys the item, cookiecutters = true. I would like to save this variable to true so when the user closes and reopens the form, each click produces 5 cookies. This is what I have come up with, yet it doesn't work.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cookiecutter == true)
    {
        cookiecutter = Convert.ToBoolean(Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter);
        cookiecutter = Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter;
    }
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cookiecutter== true)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter = cookiecutter = true;
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Thank you all for the help in advance!

Comment: Is this only a typo? Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter = cookiecutter **=** true;

Comment: No it is not, I added the double equal signs, and C# does not accept it. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: Always describe what "doesn't work" means. Is it that the `cookiecutter` property is still `false` next time you load it?

Comment: Then change that line to Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter = true; Or what is the type of the 'cookiecutter' setting?

Comment: Yes it is false when I reload the form. By saying "doesn't work" if i have Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter = cookiecutter = true; I get a red line under the whole statement.

Comment: @qqbenq cookiecutter is a bool setting, but C# accepts the code, yet when I reload the form, the number still only increases by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks weird. Try to make these changes and make sure your initial value in the settings for cookiecutter is false.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cookiecutter = Convert.ToBoolean(Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter);
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter = cookiecutter;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: This works, but now by default it goes up by 5, but I want it to go up by 1, then when the setting is clicked, it will go up by 5 and save when the user closes the form.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.. you can get the value trough

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.["cookiecutter"]
```

instead of

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.cookiecutter
```

Comment: it says identifier expected